# Remote Battery management service while SureFox Kiosk is running

Tags: battery, nexus-7, remote-control, android-versions, remote-access

I am running PAW Server and SureFox (a kiosk browser) to run some webpages. However, I am experiencing significant battery drainage, and I would like to track battery usage by services as the programs are running. Most importantly, I would like have remote management on the devices.

I am using Nexus 7 on Android 4.4.2. WiFi on both ends are guaranteed. I can't do anything on the device since I need to exit surefox to check services and battery usage; I need a service that lets me see battery usage details (top 5 services that are sucking battery) when SureFox is running.

Answer (score 0):

you might try the commercial apps and their monitoring. That would be Kioware and PROVISIO Sitekiosk

Would be easier maybe if Google had something like Samsung KNOX?
https://www.samsungknox.com/en